# ORA-01001: invalid cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an oracle error `ORA-01001: invalid cursor` in the production where a number of transactions are processed in bulk. However the same code works fine in development.

I need to know when can one have `ORA-01001: invalid cursor` in an update query. I did some googling and found that there are two possibilities of getting this error:

1. Numbers of cursors opened becomes greater than MAXCURSOR permitted?
2. An attempt to fetch is made without opening a cursor.

Has anyone faced the same  problem I had described above? Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are the common causes (see also [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01001_invalid_cursor.htm) if you don't have already).

Considering you are using two different environments (dev/prod) have you verified that the MAXCURSOR parameter is the same (or that Prod MAXCURSOR > Dev MAXCURSOR)?

You should also investigate your batch process and see if the number of data could cause your process to open more cursor in prod. Example: your batch launches a stored procedure for every department code in a departments table, and every instance of this procedure opens N cursors.

If you have - say - 3 dep. codes in dev because it is enough for your tests, and 34 department codes in Prod, you could use 10 times the cursor and get in the same situation...

Comment: @marino, The MAXCURSOR is same in both production and development environment

Comment: Are the data the same, too? Assuming you don't correctly release cursors, if you have more "work" done in prod, you will exhaust them sooner.

Comment: Under what circumstances would Oracle raise this exception for a select query which does not involve a cursor?  Hibernate is throwing this exception in my application when it runs a criteria query.